# Using ECSlidingViewController with TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ecslidingviewcontroller

I'm using [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController) in my application, it contains owns `GestureRecognizer` that looks like:

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
```

And it's preventing TableView's scrolling. When I deleted that line scroll works fine. What's wrong with my approach?

Note: `TableView` is a part of Navigation Controller. And I'm using **StoryBoards**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add the `UIGestureRecognizer` to the view of the `UINavigationController`, not the the `UITableView`.

One way to do this is to create a `UINavigationController` subclass that handles the creation of both the gesture recognizer and the instantiation of your underLeft (or underRight) view controller for the ECSlidingViewController:

```
// MyNavigationController.h
@interface MyNavigationController : UINavigationController

@end

// MyNavigationController.m
@implementation MyNavigationController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (![self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController isKindOfClass:[MyLeftMenuViewController class]]) {
        self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuViewController"];
    }

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
}

@end
```

Open the Storyboard Editor, select the navigation controller and set the Identity Inspector's Custom Class field to `MyNavigationController` (rather than the default `UINavigationController`).

Answer (score 6):

I tried the approaches you suggested,but inserting the gesture recogniser inside a subclass of UINavigationController didn't work. Strangely,placing the theoretically equivalent

```
[self.navigationController.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
```

in the TableviewController `viewWillAppear:` method does the trick instead.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
[self.parentView.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
```

in TableViewController on viewWillAppear